# Getting java.io.IOException: Is a directory: on running a web app with jboss server on linux OS

Tags: java, linux, jboss

I have to read a key store file in order to call the external API where my keystore is placed in following location : /opt/mnp/modules/com/fold/conf/main/conf/testentitiy.mnr.com.jks.
when i debug my code i could see the file path is same as above and even have file is in that path but not sure why it is throwing  **java.io.IOException: Is a directory** while it is a file present in that location but read as directory.

I have verified the keystore is proper and even keypassword is also proper not sure where it is going wrong.

Even have verified the soap client is working fine  was able to call some of API which doesn't require the keystore file
Can anyone help me identifying issue thanks in advance.

```
private KeyStore loadKeyStore(String path, String passphrase) throws IOException {
         KeyStore ks = null;
         Object strm = null;
             try {
            log.debug("Loading Keystore " + path);
            ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            strm = loader.getResourceAsStream(path);
            if (strm == null) {
               strm = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(path);         }
            if (strm == null) {
               strm = new FileInputStream(path);         }
            if (strm != null) {
               ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
               if (passphrase != null) {
                  ks.load((InputStream)strm, passphrase.toCharArray());
                   } else {
                  ks.load((InputStream)strm, (char[])null);            }
               log.debug("Keystore " + path + " loaded");
                }
         } catch (GeneralSecurityException var9) {
            throw new IOException(var9.toString(), var9);
             } finally {
            if (strm != null) {
               ((InputStream)strm).close();
                }      }
       return ks;
   }
```

Comment: Please post minimum code and stacktrace so we can see how its coded.

Comment: @locus2k I have updated code used to load keystore kindly have a look into it

Comment: Can you post how your method is being called specifically what is being passed in for the path?

Comment: Specifically where the keystore file exists before its being copied.

Comment: I am passing path as :  /opt/mnp/modules/com/fold/conf/main/conf/testentitiy.mnr.com.jks   and pass phrase is : gmerscdP1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_KEYSTORE = "testentitiy.mnr.com.jks";

private KeyStore loadKeyStore(String path, String passphrase) throws IOException {
  try {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

    Path file = Paths.get(path);
    log.debug("Loading Keystore " + path);
    if (Files.exists(file)) {
      ks.load(Files.newInputStream(file), passphrase.toCharArray());
      log.debug("Keystore " + path + " loaded");
      return ks;
    }

    log.debug("Keystore doesnt exist creating file");
      
    try(InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(DEFAULT_KEYSTORE); 
          OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(path))) {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int read = 0;
      while((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
      }
      return loadKeyStore(path, passphrase);
    }
  } catch (GeneralSecurityException var9) {
    throw new IOException(var9.toString(), var9);
  } 
}
```

This will test to see if the the passed in path file exists first and if it does we can load it directly. Otherwise it will take `DEFAULT_KEYSTORE` file; write it to the path and then try again. This code assumes the DEFAULT_KEYSTORE is packaged with the jar/war so might have to change that up and also do more error handling.

Comment: okay but i wanted to know why my file is read as directory in this case if i get that i might not even need to change code also so..is the path i am passing is proper?

Comment: I think it has something to do with `getSystemResourceAsStream` which is normally used for just loading a resource from the class path and not used to load an actual file from disk. I have hardly seen it used.

Comment: okay i tha case I suspect it is going to fileinput stream where we can use external path so..

Comment: have you stepped through it and see which line its throwing the exception at. Might be throwing the exception before it gets to the `FileInputStream`

Comment: As per exception (It is a directory) if it goes to Fileinputstream it would throw error if it is of directory type so i suspect it has created stream object via loader.getResourceAsStream(path) I am unable to debug it as error occurred only in deployed box not in my local code base so..  Apologies for delay